# Azure-cli fails to add extensions on termux

Tags: python, android, django, azure, termux

I've installed the Azure-cli on termux.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.brianlinkletter.com/install-azure-cli-on-your-android-phone/)

it works fine except when I attempt to setup "UP extension", with this command :

```
$ az extension add --name db-up
```

It gave me this error :

```
An error occurred. Pip failed with status code 1. Use --debug for more information.
```

Comment: Are you sure you install Azure CLI successfully?

Comment: It seems the pip command failed. You can check it.

Comment: How to check that !

Comment: With the debug, you can see the command just download the package from Azure storage and then install the package via pip. So you need to find the package or download it and then install it via pip.

Comment: Any updates for the current situation?